# Mongodb $set Insert is not working correctly

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have the following collection of pets:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62372a7f30847f1025d9eaaf"), "id" : 1, "name" : "Mikey", "species" : "Gerbil" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62372a7f30847f1025d9eab0"), "id" : 2, "name" : "Davey Bungooligan", "species" : "Piranha" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62372a7f30847f1025d9eab2"), "id" : 4, "name" : "Mikey", "species" : "Hotdog" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62372a7f30847f1025d9eab3"), "id" : 5, "name" : "Terrence", "species" : "Sausagedog" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62372c9430847f1025d9eab6"), "id" : 8, "name" : "Gabriel", "species" : "Naked mole rat" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6237375930847f1025d9eab9"), "id" : 7, "name" : "James", "species" : "Piranha" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6237394e30847f1025d9eabe"), "id" : 3, "name" : "Suzy B", "species" : "Cat" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6237394e30847f1025d9eabf"), "id" : 6, "name" : "Philomena Jones", "species" : "Cat" }
```

I want to insert a list of favourite food for one of the cats and have tried the following:

```
db.pets.update({name:”Suzy B”},{$set{favorites:{ food:[”Fish Soup”,”Whiskey Fish”]}}})
```

but I get the following error:

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: illegal character :
@(shell):1:21
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: same comment as to your other question: DO NOT canibalize your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot a `:` after the `$set`

and it should be double quote `"` not `”`

Here is the good request

```
{
  name: "Suzy B"
},
{
  $set: {
    favorites: {
      food: [
        "Fish Soup",
        "Whiskey Fish"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```